# Use crosshatch as filling for a shapefile that is on top of a raster with ggpattern

Tags: ggplot2, raster, ggpattern

I am plotting a shape file on top of a raster using ggplot2. I would want my shape file to be filled with a transparent crosshatch.

I read about the ggpattern package and tried using it but can not figure it out, especially because I am plotting both a raster and a shape file but want the crosshatch to be applied only to the shape file.

Here is my current code:

```
raster_plot <- ggmap(lagoon_map) +
  geom_tile(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = X262050)) +
  geom_polygon(data = shapefile, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "red") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  coord_equal()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size=10))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())+ 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", angle = 0, margin = margin(r = 17), size=10, vjust=0.5))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 6),  
        legend.title = element_text(size = 6, face= "bold", margin = margin(b=10)), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.2, "cm"))
```

Comment: Does replacing `geom_polygon()` with `geom_polygon_pattern()` not do what you want? The polygon and raster are separate geoms (and data sets) in your example, so changing how the polygon looks shouldn't change how the tile looks.